# How to return to the function level?

Tags: meteor, typescript, angular, rxjs5, angular2-meteor

I have a function `loadMessages`, I want it return an `Observable`.

```
  loadMessages(chatId: string): Observable<Message[]> {
    console.log('1');

    this.autorun(() => {
      const handle = this.subscribe('messages', chatId);

      if (handle.ready()) {
        console.log('2');

        const messages = Messages.find().fetch();
        return Observable.of(messages);  // here return is not for this function, which is useless
      }
    });

    console.log('3');  // I don't want this line run immediately

    // I wish I can return here, but I cannot
  }
```

How can I return to the function level?

Also, right now the order is 1 -> 3 -> 2. Is there any way to run 1 -> 2, and wait there until I get the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
loadMessages(chatId: string): Observable<Message[]> {
  console.log('1');

  return Observable.create(observer => {
    this.autorun(() => {
      const handle = this.subscribe('messages', chatId);

      if (handle.ready()) {
        console.log('2');

        const messages = Messages.find().fetch();
        observer.next(messages)
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Very simple example is here http://plnkr.co/edit/GADtB8QCTnNubtRu9SFv?p=preview